# Android : Scrollable Menu Bar Like Fox News App

Tags: android-layout

my app need to show user scrollable menu bar under tab bar like fox news app. Please let me know if any one has the solution.

[image: Fox News]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fadingEdgeLength="20dp"
                android:scrollbars="none" >
                <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linerHorizScrolView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/menubar6"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                        android:paddingRight="10dip"
                        android:weightSum="1" >



                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/client_tab"
                            android:layout_width="100dip"
                            android:layout_height="80dip"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/traffic_button_selector"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                            android:paddingBottom="15dip"
                            android:text="Traffic"
                            android:textColor="#707070"
                            android:textColorHighlight="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="9dip"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />






                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/criminal_client_tab"
                            android:layout_width="100dip"
                            android:layout_height="80dip"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/criminal_button_selector"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                            android:paddingBottom="15dip"
                            android:text="Criminals"
                            android:textColor="#707070"
                            android:textColorHighlight="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="9dip"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />







                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/courts_tab"
                            android:layout_width="100dip"
                            android:layout_height="80dip"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/courts_button_selector"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                            android:paddingBottom="15dip"
                            android:text="Courts"
                            android:textColor="#707070"
                            android:textColorHighlight="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="9dip"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />



                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/violation_tab"
                            android:layout_width="100dip"
                            android:layout_height="80dip"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/violation_button_selector"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                            android:paddingBottom="15dip"
                            android:text="Violations"
                            android:textColor="#707070"
                            android:textColorHighlight="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="9dip"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />



                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/support_tab"
                            android:layout_width="92dip"
                            android:layout_height="80dip"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/support_button_selector"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                            android:paddingBottom="15dip"
                            android:text="Support"
                            android:textColor="#707070"
                            android:textColorHighlight="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="9dip"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />



                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/settings_tab"
                            android:layout_width="90dip"
                            android:layout_height="80dip"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/settings"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                            android:paddingBottom="15dip"
                            android:text="Settings"
                            android:textColor="#707070"
                            android:textColorHighlight="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="9dip"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                    </LinearLayout></HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: My images will be dynamic in nature - different for different apk's(based on values in sqlite), since HorizontalScroll has no adapter support - do you know any other way this can be acheived?