# Horizontal-Scrollable menu bar with tweening animation

Tags: android, animation, scroll

I wanted to build a custom UI component which consist of a button and a menu bar.

When the button is clicked, the button will tween away from the screen, then the menu bar will tween in. The menu bar is built a set of icons scrollable horizontally. Such example is like the Fox News app where you select the type news you want from the scroll bar. Such as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701785/android-scrollable-menu-bar-like-fox-news-app).

Another example is on the app Thinking Space, when user click on the menu button and the drawing toolbar comes up. I need exactly shown on this app.

I've read several guides on building a custom UI component from android's page but have not yet got a clue on where should I start. Do I need to completely build from scratch by extending View class? If it's so, how do I implement the tweening animation, I do not know which should be drawn in onDraw() method as the bar and the button will not both appear on the screen.

Any advice or example to guide me to the light? It's my first time building custom UI components.

I'll provide more information for you to help me, if needed.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

did you think about using Tabhost , and in each Tabspec , use an HorizontalScrollView which will contains your menu

?? is  that what you want ?

in your LAyout xml :

```
<!-- scroll des pays de filtre -->
    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/scrollPays">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layoutScrollPays"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button android:id="@+id/filtrePaysPromo" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="17px" android:textColor="#fafafa" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/segment"
                android:text="Promo" android:padding="2px"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/filtrePaysMaroc" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/segment"
                android:text="Maroc" android:textSize="17px" android:textColor="#fafafa" 
                android:padding="2px" android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/filtrePaysTunisie" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/segment"
                android:text="Tunisie" android:textSize="17px" android:textColor="#fafafa" 
                android:padding="2px" android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/filtrePaysEspagne" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/segment"
                android:text="Espagne" android:textSize="17px" android:textColor="#fafafa" 
                android:padding="2px" android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/filtrePaysTurquie" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/segment"
                android:text="Turquie" android:textSize="17px" android:textColor="#fafafa" 
                android:padding="2px" android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/filtrePaysGrece" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/segment"
                android:text="Grece" android:textSize="17px" android:textColor="#fafafa" 
                android:padding="2px" android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/filtrePaysMaurice" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/segment"
                android:text="Ile Maurice" android:textSize="17px" android:textColor="#fafafa" 
                android:padding="2px" android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/filtrePaysRepDom" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/segment"
                android:text="Rep. Dominicaine" android:textSize="17px" 
                android:textColor="#fafafa" android:padding="2px" android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/filtrePaysItalie" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/segment"
                android:text="Italie" android:textSize="17px" android:textColor="#fafafa" 
                android:padding="2px" android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/filtrePaysEgypt" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/segment"
                android:text="Egypt" android:textSize="17px" android:textColor="#fafafa" 
                android:padding="2px" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

that's work for me , 
it looks like this : 
[image: see the HorizontalScrollView on the Top which contains countries]

Comment: Hmmm not really, it's more like the gallery demo in android's apidemos where you scroll over a horizontal list of images to select an image. But I want to texts instead of images

Comment: you can do this with an HorizontalScrollView, which  will contain for example 5 includes, each include contain an imageView with a TextViex centered in a FRameLayout , 
it will works :) trust me

Comment: or simply you can use a Button with background image ;) , see my edit

Comment: sounds promising, do you have an example that I might be able to refer? I have no idea where should I start :(

Comment: Ahh should have refresh the page before commenting, I think I've got the point, I'll try it out later. But I'm supposed to make this as a reusable custom UI component, is it possible?

Comment: use my xml code in a RelativeLayout , and use simple Button with Background Image as in the example , and it will works.  
For me , i used a Background Image in red, u can see that in my layout xml :) , try it ;)

Comment: yes it's possible , 
you can define this HorizontalScrollView in a layout XML , and include it in your other layouts 

take a look in includes layout xml in Android ; it's so simple ;) 
hope that's help

Comment: that really helped :) but i'm still pretty much beginner, got much more to digest haha.. thanks for the tips, i'll see what can I do with the suggestions given by you!

Comment: u're welcome :) , w're all beginners , lool (just 2 mounths ago ) :)